# :hover:before doesnt work for chrome on mac?

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, hover, pseudo-element

I was wondering if anyone has come up with this problem?

I have a pseudoelement on :before and I want to change one of its properties on hover

```
element:before {
    ....
    background: red;
}
element:hover:before {
    ....
    background: green;
}
```

it works great except from chrome on mac, where it works the first time i hover an element but then all the "before" elements using this method disappear on hover

i created a jsfiddle which replicates the problem (test on chrome/mac to see the bug)

http://jsfiddle.net/annam/vnjj5/1/

any solutions? or known bugs? havent been able to find anything on google

Comment: It's work for me i am using chrome17

Comment: Which version of Chrome and Mac OS X are you using? I’ve got Chrome 17 on Mac OS X 10.7.2, and the before element never disappears: it just turns green when I’m hovering `#test`, and stays red the rest of the time.

Comment: I'm also on Chrome 17 on Mac OS X and your JS Fiddle works fine for me.  Are you sure that the JS fiddle is 100% identical to the live code you're working with?'

Comment: its working fine with my latest chrome

Comment: Working on Chrome 24.0.1312.52

Comment: All of you - remember that Anna specified that this issue can be reproduced on Mac OS X only.

Comment: Mac OS 10.8.3, Chrome 27.0.1453.93 : It works.
Do you have the latest version ?